# Reusing variable between SocketServer requests

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, udp

I want to create temporary variable for method inside class. and update the variable inside method. and i want to reuse `self.last_l` inside loop. but it doesn't work.

here it is my code :

```
import socket, mouseapi, mouseinput
from sys import stdout, exit
from decimal import Decimal
from math import fabs
from datetime import datetime
import time
import SocketServer

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.100"
UDP_PORT = 5005


class MyUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        self.before = 0
        self.noise = 1.5
        self.noise_f = 0.8
        self.last_l = 0 # i want this temporary and updated on handle()

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        start = time.clock()
        ndata = data.replace("[","")
        ndata = data.replace("]","")
        ndata = ndata.split(", ")        
        try:
            ndata[1] = ("%.2f" % float(ndata[1]))
            atas = ndata[1]
            atas_bawah = int(int(float(atas)*100))
            selisih = fabs(float(atas)-float(self.last_l)) # used here
            if selisih > self.noise_f:
                print "Selisih -> %.2f" % float(selisih)
                print "Sensor -> %.2f" % float(atas)
                self.last_l = atas # and updated here
                atas_bawah = int(int(float(atas)*100))
                end = time.clock()
                print "Latency -> %.2gs" % (end-start)
            if self.last_l == 0:
                self.last_l = atas # or updated here
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = UDP_IP, UDP_PORT
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

So i expect to print selisih value is less than 1 or more. but it give me more than 1.

```
Selisih -> 6.53
Sensor -> 6.53
Latency -> 3.1e-05s
Selisih -> 6.70
Sensor -> 6.70
Latency -> 2.8e-05s
Selisih -> 6.97
Sensor -> 6.97
Latency -> 4.1e-05s
Selisih -> 7.15
Sensor -> 7.15
Latency -> 2.1e-05s
Selisih -> 7.14
Sensor -> 7.14
Latency -> 2.2e-05s
Selisih -> 7.14
Sensor -> 7.14
Latency -> 2.1e-05s
Selisih -> 7.05
Sensor -> 7.05
Latency -> 2.2e-05s
Selisih -> 7.02
Sensor -> 7.02
Latency -> 2.2e-05s
```

**I've tried to make last_l with global scope. still won't work.**

and I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_l' referenced before assignment` when i try to place `global last_l` followed by `last_l = 0` anywhere and change `self.last_l` to `last_l` inside `handle` method.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you mean by `it doesn't work`?

Comment: Off-topic: i see that you are indonesian.. :) Jarang ketemu orang indo disini XD

Comment: Are you sure that the statement behind your try block runs without error? I would first guess that somewhere you get ValueError and run only the `pass` line all the time. 
Note that simply passing through ValueErrors is not a good routine, because they might give you prescious info of where your error is.

Comment: it doesn't work, because `self.last_l` and i can't reuse `self.last_l` value

Comment: @Gunslinger_ Try printing something from the `except ValueError` clause, to check if it happens or not.

Comment: BTW change the sys.exit(1)  to exit(1) or better yet change the the import to import sys

Comment: It only updates `self.last_l` when `self.last_l == 0`. Also the double `int()` call on `int(int(float(atas)*100))` aren't necessary.

Comment: Are you sure there won't be a case where `selisih` is between `0` and `noise_f`?

Comment: @martineau about double int() thanks for remind. just small draft code  before i want to deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your handler cannot see updates to `self.last_l` because new instance of `MyUDPHandler` is created on every accepted request. I.e. instances of handlers are not reused.

From `BaseRequestHandler` docstring:

> This class is instantiated for each request to be handled.  The constructor sets the instance variables request, client_address and server, and then calls the handle() method.

Possible solutions:

- keep `last_l` value in global scope.
- set `last_l` to `self.server` (instance of `UDPServer` in this case)
- pass instance with `__call__(request, client_address, server)` method to `SocketServer.UDPServer` and manager `last_l` state there.

**Note**, that none of these solutions are thread safe (i.e. will only work reliably only with single-threaded server). For thread-safe solution you have to protect writes to global variable with locks.

Example of first solution (simplest one). Irrelevant lines skipped for clarity:

```
...
last_l = 0

class MyUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    ...
    def handle(self):
        global last_l
        ...
        selisih = fabs(float(atas)-float(last_l)) # used here
        if selisih > self.noise_f:
            ...
            last_l = atas # and updated here
            ...
        if last_l == 0:
            last_l = atas # or updated here
 ...
```

Comment: Would setup be called for each instance?

Comment: So you have any solution?

Comment: @Sorin, yes -- `setup()` is called for each new instance

Comment: @Gunslinger_, I've added possible solutions to the answer, let me know if you need more detailed explanation.

Comment: I tried `last_l` value in global scope. but `handle` method won't catch it.

Comment: Have you added `global last_l` on top of `handle()`?

Comment: I got `UnbounLocalError: local variable 'last_l' referenced before assignment` when i try to place `global last_l` followed by `last_l` anywhere and change `self.last_l` to `last_l` inside `handle` method.

Comment: @Gunslinger_, See the example in updated answer. I think you've used `global` incorrectly.